# rank of a orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, orthogonal-matrices

My question is,

Is every orthogonal matrix is full rank ?

Is there any specific thorem to answer this question ?
I didnt find any

Comment: For an orthogonal matrix we have that $Q^TQ=I$, so $Q^T=Q^{-1}$, what does this tell you about the rank of $Q$?

Answer (score 10):

If $A$ is orthogonal, then $AA^\top = {\rm Id}_n$, so $(\det A)^2 = 1$. In particular, $\det A \neq 0$, so $A$ is non-singular and hence has full rank.

Answer (score 6):

Another way to think about it is that the rows (or columns if you wish) of an orthogonal matrix are orthogonal. And orthogonal vectors are linearly independent.